# Using 'powerful' as a noun - "Britain's powerful"

Tags: adjectives, usage

> The bane of **Britain’s great and powerful** is a couple of inches long, has warty skin and a bright orange underbelly—and the power to disrupt some of their most heartfelt ambitions.

'Britain's great and powerful' seems to mean 'Britain's great people and powerful people'. How can I understand the usage grammatically? Can you use an adjective without following noun?

Comment: See this answer on English Language SE: https://english.stackexchange.com/a/305308/383427

Comment: You really need to give us the source.

Comment: @Lambie - article in the _Wall Street Journal_ of 24 August 2023, about newts, behind a paywall.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes, Michael but then at least we know where it came from!

Comment: @Lambie - yes, and also mentions Boris Johnson's 'Newtopia' plan.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yeah, around here we should say the high and the mighty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use an adjective such as "powerful" to mean "powerful ones" or "powerful people".  You can talk about "the poor" or "the rich", for example to mean "poor people" or "rich people".

So "great and powerful" means "great and powerful people", and "Britain's great and powerful" means "those British people who are great and powerful".

This conversion of an adjective to a noun depends on the right context. It isn't always idiomatic. In particular it is not idiomatic to talk about "a great an powerful".  The adjective as a noun refers to the collective of all people, not a single person.  So you would use *plural* agreement.  "The rich *are* getting fatter."

Comment: Indeed, in such constructions, you can read *the* as equivalent to *those who are*.